# Bizarre 3D view glitch on Linux Mint

Tags: 3d-view

Working on a project, and for some reason the viewport jerks around, sometimes to the point of being nearly unusable.  When it's rendered, there are some weird distortions of models as well.  At first I thought it was because the view clip was really big, but shrinking it didn't fix it.  Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Here's a video of what I mean:
https://youtu.be/Xg1NvfckjRo

Comment: The video doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are very far from the center of the world. You are basically loosing precision as you move away from the center. This is because blender uses floating point numbers for things as location and these can store more decimals on lower numbers and fewer at higher, moving the decimal sign but keeping the number of possible digets. Somewhat simplified...

Anyway, move you scene closer to the centre and you should be fine.

This problem is not related to platform and not unique for Blender.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice how far away I was!  That fixes everything, thank you!